# Number decimal length with query

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I got this :

HTML

```html
<span class="EURCOUNT"></span>
```

JS

```js
$(".EURCOUNT").text(query.eurcount)
```

This return me like, `0.0642857142857143` for some results. I try so many time Google-it but i can't fix my problem...

```js
$(".EURCOUNT").text(query.eurcount.toFixed(4)) // doesn't work
```

My number EURCOUNT was called inside that span

```js
var query = getQueryParams(document.location.search);

$(".amount").text(query.amount);
$(".EURCOUNT").text(query.eurcount);
$(".USDTCOUNT").text(query.usdt);

function getQueryParams(qs) {
  qs = qs.split('+').join(' ');
  var params = {},
    tokens, re = /[?&]?([^=]+)=([^&]*)/g;
  while (tokens = re.exec(qs)) {
    params[decodeURIComponent(tokens[1])] = decodeURIComponent(tokens[2]);
  }
  return params;
}
```

I just want remove decimal and get only 4 after my point (like 0.1234)

Thanks all

Comment: `$(".EURCOUNT").text(query.eurcount.toFixed(4)) dosnt work` Is there an error in your console?

Comment: What does the `getQueryParams` function look like?

Comment: @epascarello  function getQueryParams(qs) {
                qs = qs.split('+').join(' ');

                var params = {},
                    tokens,
                    re = /[?&]?([^=]+)=([^&]*)/g;

                while (tokens = re.exec(qs)) {
                    params[decodeURIComponent(tokens[1])] = decodeURIComponent(tokens[2]);
                }

                return params;
            }

Comment: Yes .. "Uncaught TypeError: query.ethcount.toFixed is not a function"

Comment: So you have a string and not a number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

query.eurcount will return a string value you should parse it to a float before toFixed method

```js
$(".EURCOUNT").text(Number.parseFloat(query.eurcount).toFixed(4))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [Location: search](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/search), you need to access the params by key like a `Map`, not an `Object`.

You can format currency using [`Intl.NumberFormat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat).

```js
const formatUsd = n =>
  new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', { style: 'currency', currency: 'USD' }).format(n);

const formatEuro = n =>
  new Intl.NumberFormat('de-DE', { style: 'currency', currency: 'EUR' }).format(n);

const search = document.location.search || '?amount=10.00&eurcount=10.00&usdt=12.14'; 
const query = new URLSearchParams(search);

console.log(document.location.search);

document.querySelector('.amount').textContent = query.get('amount');
document.querySelector('.EURCOUNT').textContent = formatEuro(query.get('eurcount'));
document.querySelector('.USDTCOUNT').textContent = formatUsd(query.get('usdt'));
```

```css
body { display: flex; flex-direction: column; }
body span { margin-bottom: 0.5em; }
```

```html
<span class="amount"></span>
<span class="EURCOUNT"></span>
<span class="USDTCOUNT"></span>
```